# How to remove dictionaries from list with keys matching another list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
idlist = ['101', '102']
```

```
myd = [
    {'id':'101', 'role': 'tester'},
    {'id':'102', 'role': 'tester'},
    {'id':'103', 'role': 'tester'}
]
```

- I have `idlist`
- I need to check if a dictionary with the id is present in `myd`
- I need to remove the items with matching id

Expected output:

101 and 102 are deleted

```
[{'id':'103', 'role': 'tester'}]
```

Code is below

```
for ids in idlist:
    for each in myd.items():
        if ids == each['id']
             del each
```

Do I need to do 2 for loop function to resolve this?

Comment: `myd` is a list so `myd.items()` won't do anything. You need to break down your problem into steps instead of trying to tackle everything at the same time.

Comment: The condition being `ids['id'] not in idlist`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple comprehension:

```
s = set(idlist)  # better membership test than list

myd[:] = [d for d in myd if d['id'] not in s]
```

It is usually better to build a list from scratch than to repeatedly remove elements. The slice assignment `myd[:] = ...` just makes sure this is a mutation on the existing list object as removing elements would be.

Answer (score 2):

A single liner:

```
myd = [x for x in myd if x['id'] not in idlist]
```

Esentially creates a new list with the values that are not in idlist. You can assign this to `myd` if you like to overwrite it.

NOTE: This is not deleting from the list but rather replacing the list.